# Error message git push from my local rails app , log/development.log too large

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, logging, github, push

I have a question , I want to push my app on git but when I try to but I received a message "log/development file exceds 100MB".

So I try cmd :
- **rake log:clear => Nothing changes**
- **git rm --cached  => Nothing changes** 
- **git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch log/development.log' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all**
- **echo log >> .gitignore**
-**git rm log/development.log
git commit -m "removed log file"**

But when I do git status then git add . then git commit -m then push I still have this error message , so I check my log/development file and is empty

My question is why git still display this error message??

Please Heeeeeelp

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need push `log` file that's why you need to ignore this file for `git push` like below

If you initialize repsitory then automatically added a file which name `.gitignore` like

```
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Initialize repo"
#=> if you not added before
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git #=> example user
$ git push
```

That's it, but in case if `.gitignore` file setup missing something then you can get it manually like below

```
#=> project/.gitignore
# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
/log/*
/tmp/*
!/log/.keep
!/tmp/.keep
```

Hope to help.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could do is remove the file from the repo's history:

`bfg --delete-files development.log`

Hopefully that's useful to you.

Warning: Extremely destructive.